# Repeated reminder email from EasyJet for API document

Tags: air-travel, easyjet, geneva

I'm flying to Geneva (Switzerland) in few days with EasyJet with my wife.  I have provided both our passport details for advance passenger information.  But keep on getting emails from EasyJet to add these API documents before travelling.  Is this normal?  I would have thought they would check this before sending me the reminder emails.

Comment: "API documents" sounds like an odd phrase. Could you paste or type in a sentence or two from the email? It could even be an error message from a software bug in their website messing up the email.

Comment: I flew with EJ recently and had the same situation. Don't worry, as long as you've given the details you'll be fine.

Comment: @hippietrail I think in this case, API = Advance Passenger Information.  But as a developer, seeing API clearly means something else to us ;)

Answer (score 9):

A budget airline has to cut costs somewhere, and EasyJet cuts its IT budget (hey, better than skimping on plane maintenance, right?). As a result, its website and back-end systems tend to be somewhat buggy. I've noticed similar quirks before when I used EasyJet, so I'd say don't worry about it, and just bring the documents when you check in.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're referring to APIS - [Advance Passenger Information System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System). The documents themselves are called 'API' (Advance Passenger Information) documents, so it's not a bug. Technically, filling this in is only compulsory when you're flying to the US, so when you're flying with EasyJet within Europe you shouldn't worry. At the time you check-in, they can update your personal information in case it already hasn't been logged into their system.

Comment: Ankur, that's not quite accurate. Both the UK and Spain require API these days too.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't stress about these emails, or the advanced notification at all. The emails are usually a way of organizing information about the passengers, but in my opinion, are rarely used for actual travel, or immigration. You ALWAYS have to provide original documents at the time of check-in. It is at this time that the authenticity is checked and boarding is permitted. I fly British Airways often, and am inundated with API emails, even though they have all my information...At the time of check-in (and in case of LHR, at the time of boarding too), passports are checked foremost, even before the actual boarding pass.

Enjoy Geneva - hear it's beautiful!

Comment: That's not quite accurate. Although I agree with your point about not stressing over it (!), there is a benefit to making sure your API information is accurate - you can check-in online and avoid the check-in desk entirely (assuming you only have hand luggage, etc.). Of course, when you check in online, it will force you to enter API information at that point if it's not already in the system.

Comment: If you are flying internationally, there is no way that you can bypass the check-in counter solely based on API and online check-in. I have yet to come across such an arrangement, regardless of the traveler's nationality.

Comment: Not true. I have flown from the UK->US like this several times. As long as you have filled in the API information before, you don't need to go anywhere near the check-in counter as long as you only have hand luggage.

Comment: e.g. http://www.americanairlines.co.uk/i18n/travelInformation/onlineCheckin.jsp - "If you are travelling with carry-on luggage head straight to the departure gates." I don't doubt there are some situations where airlines force you to check documents with them at the airport, but it isn't true to say this is _always_ the case.